# Entity must be managed to call remove

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

What's going on here?

```java
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AppointmentCommentDao {
    public void delete(long appointmentCommentId) {
        AppointmentComment ac = em.find(AppointmentComment.class, appointmentCommentId);
        if (ac != null)
        {
            em.merge(ac);
            em.remove(ac);
        }
    }
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

On the call to `remove` I get an `IllegalArgumentException` with the message being `Entity must be managed to call remove: ...., try merging the detached and try the remove again.`

Comment: Solved it with em.find(...) method.

Answer (score 19):

In your case merge is not needed, because ac is not deattached in any point between *em.find* and *em.remove*.

In general when entity is deattached, EntityManager's method **merge** takes entity as argument and **returns managed instance**. Entity given as argument does not transform to be attached. This is explained for example here: [EntityManager.merge](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29). You have to go for:

```
    AppointmentComment toBeRemoved = em.merge(ac);
    em.remove(toBeRemoved);
```

Comment: Strange... With no change to that code (although there were other unrelated changes), it mysteriously started working. I even removed the merge altogether because the whole reason I had it in the first place was that I was getting that exception. It shouldn't be necessary because the entity should be attached while we're in the same persistence context that loaded it. Something else was going on I think. Stupid GlassFish.

Comment: I do take your point, though, that you're supposed to use the object returned from the merge going forward, not the passed in object. +1

Comment: You are absolutely right, your code should work without merge, because ac is not deattached in any point. I first assumed that it was oversimplified example. I will update answer.

Comment: Working perfectly for new entity reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
entity = getEntityManager().getReference(AppointmentComment.class, entity.getId());
getEntityManager().remove(entity);
```

Comment: This answer is not useful because it doesn't give any explanation to the problem.